# Unable to access AWS S3 from Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

get the exception :

```
Unable to execute HTTP request: Unable to resolve host "cognito-identity.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com": No address associated with hostname
Unable to resolve host "cognito-identity.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com": No address associated with hostname
```

The code is the following :

```
        // Initialize the Amazon Cognito credentials provider
        CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                getApplicationContext(), // Application Context
                getResources().getString(R.string.AWS_IdentityPoolId), // Identity Pool ID
                Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1 // Region enum
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is  "just" question of Region. As my Cognito is in IRELAND, and my Bucket in Franckfurt,a confusion is easy. So you may be carefull on region. In may case :

```
// Initialize the Amazon Cognito credentials provider
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
       getApplicationContext(), // Application Context
       getResources().getString(R.string.AWS_IdentityPoolId), // Identity Pool ID
       Regions.EU_WEST_1 // Region enum
);
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI, Cognito Identity isn't available in EU_CENTRAL_1 (Frankfurt) yet. Checkout [AWS Service Region Availability](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html). Like Anthony said, Cognito Identity doesn't have to be in the same region of other services. Please always choose regions close to you for better experience.